# Can Python execute the exe files by their shortcuts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-os

I have a Python 3 file named `launch.py` which tries to launch application using shortcuts. I have a folder named `Apps` in which I have shortcuts of almost every app I have in my PC.

Here is part of `launch.py`:

```
import os

cm = input("Type the file name : ")
print("Launching " + cm)
os.startfile("C:\Test\Apps\\" + cm.lower() + ".Ink")
```

Usage:

```
Type the file name : chrome
```

Unfortunately, this crashes the script. I have checked the existence of `chrome.Ink` in the `Apps` folder. Where am I going wrong? Can this be done?

Comment: You need to add one more slash after the `C:` and after the `Test`. I tried to use `os.startfile` to start `Spotify.lnk` that on my Desktop and its works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce a slash (`\`), you have to write two, if you write one Python would consider it empty.
Also, you wrote `Ink` instead of `lnk`. `lnk` means a link to the original file, so you need to write it correct.

`"C:\\Test\\Apps\\" + cm.lower() + ".lnk"`

Try this:

```
import os

cm = input("Type the file name : ")
print(f'Launching {cm}')
os.startfile("C:\\Test\\Apps\\" + cm.lower() + ".lnk")
```

Answer (score 2):

The filename isn't `chrome.Ink` (with a capital `I`) but rather `chrome.lnk` (with a lowercase `l`), where [`lnk` is short for "link"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows). Change the extension you're using in your code.